# Dequeue in C program

Tags: c, queue, implementation

```
client removeClient (client cList,int pos)
{
int i,data;
data=cList[0];  **
pos=pos-1;
for (i=0;i<pos;i++)
{
    cList[i]=cList[i+1]; **
}
return data;

}/* end module*/
```

Having a bit of trouble with this section of my code.
**-> at these lines I'm getting the error that says... subscripted value is neither array nor pointer nor vector.
What does that mean?

Comment: What's the definition of `client`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are passing a scalar value, passing a pointer will help

```
client removeClient (client* cList,int pos){ }
```

This way you can pass an array to your function.

Call the function using

```
client result = removeClient(clientQueue, index);
```

Comment: Yes, this is insignificant. After all a `struct` is just a use-defined type.

Comment: Ok will do. What about the first line that has '**', there is still an error there?

Comment: You can't assign your `struct` to a primitive. Both are of different types! Make `data` of type `client`.

Comment: @bash.d Also add that how OP should call this function. As you remember that he is implementing queue and having `clientQueue` array.

Comment: @bash.d Oh, oops! Silly me. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Just adding to @bash.d answer with some additional points:

As know from your previous question you are truing to remove first element(client) from an array of client.

```
client removeClient (client* cList,int pos)
{
 int i;
 client data=cList[0];  // data is client type
 pos=pos-1;
 for (i=0;i<pos;i++)
 {
    cList[i]=cList[i+1]; 
 }
 return data;
}
```

remember that  `data` is not int but client type (read comment)   And you should call this function like, in main:

```
client date;
data = removeClient ( clientQueue,pos);
```

Comment: Does this mean I cannot have... "return data;"

Comment: @user1 see your `cList` array in `removeClient` function is of Client type. All its elements are client type you `int data = cList[0]` is wrong.

Comment: Oh, so then what should it be?

Comment: @user1 Read my answer I declare `data` as `client` type  that is also  your function's return type. I declared `Client data;` notice my commented line in answer code

Comment: So I will return what? data or client?

Comment: @user1 obviously `data` See The code I have given in my answer is correct I also shown that how to call your function. Please try bit hard.